# How to get data from a rest API asynchronously in realtime in Angular

Tags: angular, rest, rxjs, observable

In my component file i use the http client to get an observable of the json file from an api endpoint:

```
this.data =  this.http.get(api);
```

in the template i am binding the data field using the async pipe:

```
<td *ngFor="let post of (data | async)"> {{post.title}} </td>
```

Now i am getting the data, the problem is that i want it to happen in realtime without having to refresh the page.
So is there anyway i can achieve asynchronous data loading

P.S
I have already tried some workarounds like setting interval to continuously subscribe to the observable but that would just deplete resources and it seems like there's another cleaner way that i am missing.

Comment: Do you mean constantly hitting the endpoint for new data?

Comment: You could either use websockets if you really want realtime. Or you can use polling mechanism in which you could hit the API every 1 or 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything at front side for making it real time. 
Async pipe will keep eye on response but in order to get response you must have to hit 
API after some Time interval or something similar. As you already said it's not cleaner solution. You can achieve this using web socket which is back end thing.
Some of databases are real time in nature by default. Firebase is one of them.